# Python/Django is importing the wrong module (relative when it should be absolute)

Tags: python, django, django-templates, python-import

I'm using Django 1.2 pre-alpha and Python 2.4. Yeah, I know, but I'm stuck with it. We can't upgrade at the moment and I doubt that's the answer anyway.

I've got two template tag libraries, `foo` and `bar`. However, `foo` is also the name of a top-level package, and it happens to be the package of `bar`:

```
foo-1.2.3/
  foo/
    conf/
      settings.py
    templatetags/
      bar.py

bar-4.5/
  somepackage/
    templatetags/
      foo.py
```

The tag library `bar.py` contains a line like this:

```
from foo.conf import settings
```

...and you would expect it to load `foo-1.2.3/foo/conf/settings.py`.

But no:

> TemplateSyntaxError: 'bar' is not a valid tag library: Could not load template library from django.templatetags.bar, No module named conf

Unfortunately, Django performs [a little magic](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/dec/04/magic-tags/) and binds all template tag libraries to `django.templatetags.*`. Thus, `bar` is being imported as `django.templatetags.bar`, and when it calls `from foo.conf import settings` it ends up importing `bar-4.5/somepackage/templatetags/foo.py`. Ugh!

**Do you have any ideas how to fix this?**

I've set a breakpoint right before the import, and I've confirmed that `foo-1.2.3` is at the beginning of `sys.path`, but the `import` keyword still finds the wrong `foo`.

If it helps, note that I can modify the `foo-1.2.3` package (because it's been checked in locally and is being phased out), but I refuse to modify the `bar-4.5` package (because it's an open-source package and has been installed system-wide).

Comment: rename `foo/`? btw, on Python >= 2.5 you could use `from __future__ import absolute_import` http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html ☃

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few more hours of hacking, this did the trick.

Original code:

```
from foo.conf import settings
```

New code:

```
foo = __import__('foo')
conf = __import__('foo.conf').conf
settings = __import__('foo.conf.settings').conf.settings
```

(I probably don't need the second line.)

Ewww.