# Why is Django missing the custom context processor?

Tags: processor, django-1.6, django-context

### My django 1.6 project is structured:

- cg1

  - cg1

    - settings.py
    - cont_proc.py
    - inti, etc.
  - app
  - app
  - manage.py
  - templates

### cont_proc.py reads:

```
from django.conf import settings

def misc(request):
    return {'SITE_URL': settings.SITE_URL,'BALANCED_API_KEY':settings.BALANCED_API_KEY}`
```

### in settings.py I have:

```
import django.conf.global_settings as DEFAULT_SETTINGS
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = DEFAULT_SETTINGS.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cg1.cont_proc.misc'),)
BALANCED_API_KEY = os.environ.get('BALANCED_API_KEY')
SITE_URL = 'www.mysite.com'  #but set up
```

### python manage.py shell:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
['django_balanced.context_processors.balanced_library','django_balanced.context_processors.balanced_settings', 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth']

>>>>import os
>>>>os.environ.get('BALANCED_API_KEY')
'correct key from a local .env file'
```

I've tried quite a few so question, especially: [Where is template context processor in Django 1.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446558/where-is-template-context-processor-in-django-1-5)

also: [Python/Django is importing the wrong module (relative when it should be absolute)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521416/python-django-is-importing-the-wrong-module-relative-when-it-should-be-absolute)

but django doesn't seem to see my custom context processor, cont_proc, in the shell. And when I use render in views my templates do not receive the variables.

Answer (score 1):

I had installed django-balanced. Apparently this was a mistake. I removed from installed apps and all was good.