# Python imports with leading dot no longer recognised going from py3 to py2 in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-import

I've copied a project I worked on with python3 to a workstation that only has python2. Python is now complaining about one of my imports.

The line is

```
from .mage.models import ButtLoadOfClasses
```

The error however says

```
ImportError: No module named mage.models
```

My project tree looks like this:

```
nwod-db-master/
    characters
         mage
             models.py
         admin.py
```

The import is in the admin.py.

So I presume it's chopping off the dot, and then treating it as an absolute import - mage.models is not on my path so it barfs.

I've searched for this and most relevant thing I can find is here [What's wrong with relative imports in Python?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/159503/42685) which is more about coding style, and doesn't lead me to a solution - except that it leads me to believe that relative imports are a python3 only thing. I also saw this: [Python/Django is importing the wrong module (relative when it should be absolute)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4521416/1075247) but that is for template tags. I've yet to resort to the hackery in the accepted answer, as I'm hoping things have moved on in the last ~4 years.

How do I force python to import this as an absolute reference to the package?

Comment: Which sub version of Python 2?

Comment: @Selcuk it's 2.7.6 I'll add the versions in to the tags, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Can you post your project tree and the name of the file that has the import statement?

Comment: Do you have a file named `__init__.py` in `characters/mage/`? Otherwise it won't be recognized as a module in Python 2.

Comment: @knbk that solved it, but it looks like [devhallo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29284684/1075247) beat you to an answer.

Comment: I beat him by half a minute ;) - not that it matters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are not including an `__init__.py` file in mage/, so it is not recognised as a packages.

just add an `__init__.py` file under mage/

```
nwod-db-master/
    characters/
         mage/
             __init__.py
             models.py
         admin.py
```